# Any API works like Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs and can be used in .NETFramework 4.5.2 project?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I plan to use the [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) to push notification through Azure notification hub in backend service of an existed project. However, I found that the project is using .NETFramework 4.5.2. As the document stated, the SDK has dependecy to .NETFramework 4.6.1 or higher.

Since the existed project is already developed well and problems could appear if I upgrade. Any other solutions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to you don't want to upgrade to `.Net Framework 4.6.1 or higher`. You can use `REST API`, create `HttpClient` in your existed project to send `Http Request`.

[（notificationhubs）REST API methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/notificationhubs/rest-api-methods)

You can use [HttpHelper](https://github.com/Jason446620/ConsoleProj/blob/master/ODatafilter/HttpHelper.cs) in my sample code.

[image]

Comment: It definitely helps! 
In addition, I just found another method: using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs old version 1.0.9. It do not have dependency to .net core or framework. However, is it a common workaround too? I tested it is also work but I am afraid since the version is too old.

Comment: @Kwan The old version can be used as long as it can be downloaded through nuget.

Comment: @Kwan It's just that the version may be updated. There are some methods or properties that have been updated, and the old SDK will not be supported. The other core functions are the same.